# Gridview to Excel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a gridview with `AutoGenerateDeleteButton`

[image]

And i export this gridview simple this code..

```
Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Avukat.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />");
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

There is no problem with that.

But in the excel there is a delete column :))

[image]

How can i delete the delete column in excel?

Comment: Are you sure that the correct question is how to delete the delete column **in Excel**? ;)
Your Grid will be rendered as HTML-Table and hence automatically displayed in excel like a normal worksheet. If you want to avoid this column, you have to hide it, for example:
`foreach (TableRow row in GridView1.Controls[0].Controls)
{
      row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is you want 2 x "views" of your grid.  With & without the delete column.

One for the browser, and one for Excel.

On your export, drop the delete column.  Something something like:

```
    GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = false;
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />");
```

Comment: After changing GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = false, you might need to call GridView1.DataBind(); first before Rendering.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the column from the `GridView` before exporting it.

Answer (score 2):

...Or, you can Export to a real Excel 2007 `.xlsx` file the proper way, using the `OpenXML` libraries.

Using this C# library, you just need to include the `CreateExcelFile` class in your application, and call one function:

```
DataSet ds = CreateSampleData();
CreateExcelFile.CreateExcelDocument(ds, "C:\\Sample.xlsx");
```

Full source code, and a demo application are provided, free of charge.
http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm

Good luck !